# Graphics card settings in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I've installed a Ubuntu live install with persistence mode on a USB stick using Linux Live USB creator. (Windows got corrupted while changing a .sys file, partition table was saved.)

My system gets over heated, a friend told me that this is due to inappropriate graphics card settings. I have Nvidia Geforce GT 540M Cuda 2 GB graphics card.

please, tell me what can I do so that I am able to use linux in my system without getting it overheated.

Comment: What is the problem you want us to solve? Please be clear.

Comment: @TapanAnand I have updated the problem, please see it :-)

Comment: I am not sure if the problem is due to the graphics card. Most laptops get extremely heated when running Ubuntu. May be proper dusting will work. Or maybe the heat sink is faulty.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have googled before posting repeated questions.

Anyway for determining issues related with heating, you can install a palckage like `lm-sensors` (`lm_sensors` to run command 'sensors') so as to see if your system really heats up.(Lm-sensors gives current temperature of the system).

Next try installing power consumption management utility such as `powertop`. If these are not behind the issue then have installed your graphics card driver from nVidia available at  nVidia official site.
Alternatively if you are not using the extra graphics have generic installed or disable it. Even if this could not solve your heating issue then you only know what process are behind your CPU.

Best of Luck, have hot CPU like you prefer hot girl, coffee and many moooo.

[image]

For persistence mode, I prefer to disable the graphics itself if it is the issue behind.

Comment: Actually, I googled it but couldn't find an exact solution.
p.s I prefer hot coffee over hot girls :-P